# Adding a setter to a derived interface

Tags: c#, interface, getter-setter

Is it possible somehow to achieve this behavior in C#:

```
public interface IReadOnly
{
    Data Value { get; }
}

internal interface IWritable : IReadOnly 
{
    Data Value { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to expose a readonly interface to outside assemblies, but use a writable interface internally (which I could also implement in different ways).

I know I can use an **abstract class** which implements `IReadOnly` but adds setters, but that forces me to derive all internal implementations from that class.

Comment: @Nick: good point, but setter is converted to a `setValue` method under the hood anyway. I am wondering why this is not allowed.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This isn't a problem:

```
public interface IReadOnly {
    Data Value { get; }
}

internal interface IWritable : IReadOnly {
    new Data Value { get; set; }
}

internal class Impl : IWritable {
    public Data Value { get; set; }
}
```

The Impl.Value property implementation takes care of *both* IReadOnly.Value and IWritable.Value, as demonstrated in this test snippet:

```
        var obj = new Data();
        var target = new Impl();
        var irw = (IWritable)target;
        irw.Value = obj;
        var iro = (IReadOnly)target;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(Object.ReferenceEquals(iro.Value, obj));
```

Comment: oh, that's great news. I saw that I could achieve it using the `new` keyword, but thought that it will somehow hide the base value (or make me implement `IReadOnly` explicitly).

Comment: @Hans : Also, iirc, if you set Impl as "public class Impl : IReadOnly, IWritable" anything outside the current namespace will see Impl as IReadOnly ONLY and anything inside the namespace will see Impl as IReadOnly AND IWritable. Right?

Comment: @Tipx - the OP declared IWritable internal.  Which *requires* that Impl is internal as well.  All that's visible from the outside is IReadOnly.  Whatever code creates an instance of Impl and exposes the interface will have to live inside that same assembly.

Comment: Took me a long time to find this amazing solution. Let me add here the search key words which I used originally (and failed...): "C# pair of interfaces, properties readonly writable".

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly a cop-out, but what I prefer to do is the following:

```
public interface IReadOnly
{
  Data Value { get; }
}

internal interface IWritable : IReadOnly 
{
  void SetValue(Data value);
}
```

While Hans Passant's answer works, I find it annoying that with certain inheritance trees, code using a descendant interface can still complain that it doesn't know which version of "Value" you are referring to -- even with the setter!

Answer (score -1):

For this to work well, one should declare and implement an IReadWrite, which inherits both IReadable and IWritable, and includes a "new" read-write property.  Otherwise an interface that has separate get and set properties, but no get-set property, will be neither readable nor writable.

Answer (score -4):

Hans Passant gave a very good answer and I've come to a similar answer, but I think I may be able to do one better:

```
public interface IReadOnly : IWritable
{
    new int MyValue { get; }
}

public interface IWritable
{
    int MyValue { get; set; }
}

public class Implementation : IReadOnly
{
    public int MyValue { get; private set; }

    int IWritable.MyValue
    {
        set { MyValue = value; }
        get { return MyValue; }
    }

    public static Implementation GetMyImplementation()
    {
        return ImplementationGateway<Implementation>.GetMyImplementation();
    }
}


public class ImplementationGateway<TImplementation>
    where TImplementation : class, IWritable, new()
{
    public static TImplementation GetMyImplementation()
    {
        return new TImplementation
            {
                MyValue = 1
            };
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
        Implementation myImplementation = Implementation.GetMyImplementation();
        myImplementation.MyValue = 0; //This will and is supposed to fail
    }

}
```

The difference between my and mr. Passant's solution, is that my IReadOnly inherits from my IWritable. As a result of this code, you can't set MyValue within the Program class, which may be how you want it to work. Retrieve and map the data in your Gateway class, but then have it as a read only value beyond that. With that, you have read/write separation.
As an added bonus, the only thing your DAL knows about your objects, is the interface they share as a manner of 'contract'.
**I**nterface **D**efined **M**odel.

Comment: `IReadOnly : IWritable` is a contract that says that `IReadOnly` supports everything `IWritable` supports. Hiding `MyValue` and making it read-only violates the liskov substitution principle. Furthermore, you can simply cast `Implementation` to `(IWritable)Implementation`, and suddenly you can modify it. The `IWritable` interface is even public currently.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't violate the LSP, since:
1) The interfaces are doing the hiding, not the classes.
2) There's only one class that implements the interfaces and there's no inheritance that gives a different meaning or outcome on its implemented properties. There is no modification of supertype properties by a subtype.

So please, be more specific where you think I violated the LSP.

If you take the responsibility of casting the object to a writable type, you need to take responsibility for its state. The cast is a conscious act. It is not something one does 'by accident'.

Comment: "The cast is a conscious act" - this statement holds true only for the case of casting a general type to a specific one. (So in Hans' answer if you casted `IReadable` to `IWritable` it would be a consioucs act). But in your case it is the other way around. `IReadOnly` *is* a specific case of `IWritable`, casts can happen silently, e.g. by passing the object to a method, or by using LINQ `allObjects.OfType<IWritable>()`, etc. As for the LSP, you might have a point there - I would state that it is a grey zone where we could start an endless dispute. It is not exactly as clear as I claimed.

Comment: "I would state that it is a grey zone where we could start an endless dispute.", I absolutely agree, which is why I sent an email to professor Liskov (I daren't presume she'll find the time).
In regards to casts silently happening, I still don't see that. If you have a method that accepts an IWritable as a parameter or by using LINQ extension methods, like allObjects.OfType<IWritable>(), you're being very explicit about what you expect that object to be. Now if your point is that it requires explicitly clear naming conventions, I agree wholeheartedly.

Comment: @Marsupilami - If you are logged in when editing your question, the edit will show up immediately instead of waiting for a review.

Comment: @martinstoeckli, I thought I was, but I may have been derping. Thanks for the heads up. ;)

Comment: @Marsupilami: I think you may have a point there. It's all about interface inheritance versus class inheritance. Your `Implementation` must be exlicitly cast to `IWritable` before write access is allowed.

Comment: I meant `allObjects.OfType<IWritable>` to be an example of a programmer's intention to say "give me all objects that I am allowed to write to", expecting to only get the ones that are not read-only. However the result would be all objects since the read-only onces inherit from `IWritable`, too, and the statement would even cast them underway so the programmer will unintentionally end up writing to them.

Comment: The IReadable inherits from IWritable, which means that IReadable is IWritable, but less accessible. The comparison you need to make is as follows: ICat inherits from IAnimal. If you cast a collection of ICat to IAnimal, you have a collection that exposes everything that is exposed in IAnimal, not a subset of the ICat collection that may or may not be IAnimal. They all inherently are IAnimal. The way you can see it is as follows: ICat inherits from ICatWritable. ICat limits access to certain properties, but otherwise you're talking about two interfaces describing the same 'thing'.

Comment: There are no partial interfaces and if you separate the two interfaces, without them knowing about each other, the system (rightfully) doesn't know what you're on about when you offer a IReadonly from BLL to a DAL which expects an IWritable or vice versa. The inheritance can't be switched around for the decoupling I've made, because you'd end up with the same situation as with the two separate interfaces. These are the logical limits. So it comes down to a clear and concise naming convention, which should reflect what you can expect from an interface. Which you should do at any rate.

Comment: The semantics of `public interface IReadOnly : IWritable` just seem wrong. That says that "something that is readonly is something that is writable and...". In fact, the wording of "ReadOnly" is problematic as well. It should be `IReadable`, since there is nothing about the interface that *prevents* writing, it just declares that it can be read.

Comment: The code is merely to illustrate the technical side of the matter. Naturally we can debate semantics and/or naming conventions, but those may vary between people's point of view. The way I see it, if semantics is where the critique has come to, the pattern may be deemed viable. ;)