# C# How to override a field which only has a get method?

Tags: c#, overriding

> Hi, How can i override a field which only has a get method?

```
public class Person {
    virtual protected string Name {
        get;
    }
}
```

> But i would like to have a set method too......

```
public class German : Person {
    override protected string Name {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

> How can i achieve it? please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# How to add a property setter in derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637588/c-sharp-how-to-add-a-property-setter-in-derived-class)

Comment: This might help too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749022/adding-a-setter-to-a-derived-interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637588/c-sharp-how-to-add-a-property-setter-in-derived-class) question, it's impossible to add a setter to an inheriting class when the base class does not have one. One option is using the `new` keyword, but that will replace the property.

Comment: This answer does not anything to the answers already given in the linked questions. If you think the question is a duplicate, simply flag it as such instead of repeating already posted answers.